# C++/QT/OpenMP : Threads seems to wait when access to the same instance

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, openmp

I use `C++`, `Qt` and `OpenMP` on a algorithm which make some process on a graph (arcs and nodes). The class `Node` use a static class which manage the graph (class `Graph`) with adjacency list of pointers on nodes. I can ask the successors or predecessors of a node and I receive a `QList` of pointer on nodes.

The goal is to find some constrained paths in the graph.

I use `OpenMP` to parallelize the algorithm. A good point is each thread has his own list of tasks and no resources need to be shared or protected by mutual exclusion. But each thread reads the same instance of the graph or read some information on the nodes. Graph and nodes are shared, but only for reading.

When I use `n` threads, the computation time is `n` times the sequential time. Why? Are the threads waiting if they use the same method on a same instance? All the `Qt` structures I use are reentrant. Mine should be too, except for the fact that I use static members. But nothing is modifying.

Any ideas ?

Comment: A good profiler could help to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. I use QDateTime and I often use toTime_t() to convert the date into integer. It's time consuming. I thought the integer was a member. I think it computes each time the date.

But I don't understand the difference of time I had. If I use 1 thread, the parallel part takes 400ms. If I divide the problem into 4 threads it takes 1600ms in parallel !! But if I execute the 4 threads one by one, each takes 100ms with a total of 400ms. Does the function use system call or use a thread-safe static conversion ?

Anyway, now it works fine ! I store one time the result of toTime_t() inside my class.